# Call an access function outside access with VB NET

Tags: .net, sql, ms-access

I would like to call a custom created function in access from VB NET. For example I created a myRoundNumber function in Access when i create a query in access with that function it works but outside it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use custom Access functions in a query outside of Access.