# Receiving values back after calling a sub in Access through .NET

Tags: c#, vba, ms-access

I am creating an C# application that must call subs in an Access mdb database file.

I've created a test sub in the mdb file and I can call it from C# and also pass it parameters. That all works fine, but I want to pass a result back to C#. I know I can't do this with a function, so is it possible to pass the variables by reference, then vba can change the variables and I get my result back? I tried the following, but it doesn't work. Anybody know if this is possible?

Thanks

**VBA test sub:**

```
Sub test(Byref p1 As String)
   p1="bar"
   MsgBox p1
End Sub
```

**Call it from C#:**

```
Access.Application oAccess = new Access.Application();
oAccess.Visible = true;
oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase("d:\\tmp\\test1.mdb", false, "");
string t;
t = "foo"
oAccess.Run("test", t);
//t still equals "foo" at this point, it should be equal to "bar"
```

Comment: Why can't you use a function?

Comment: I feel obliged to mention that, although it is interesting that this can be achieved, there aren't many circumstances where such a function couldn't be created directly in C#.

Comment: @Andy. Good point, I didn't consider that.

Comment: @Layman: I read it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548762/call-an-access-function-outside-access-with-vb-net . But I just tested it and I can create a function! Guess I shouldn't believe everything I read on SO.

Comment: @Johan: Regarding your comments above, the OP (in that question) asked about a function written in MSAccess and used inside the SQL query from c#. I haven't tried it and don't know if it will work. There is nothing to not believe it unless you have answer to invalidate it.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't understand it like that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For a scalar (a simple number, string, or Boolean) the system makes a
>   copy of the current value and passes this copy to the called
>   procedure.  Upon return from the called procedure the system discards
>   the copy.  So, even if the called procedure changes the value of a
>   ByVal argument, there is no way for that change to propagate back to
>   the caller.

Take a look at [this](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1022_ByRef_Argument_with_the_Application_Run_method.shtml) for explanation on passing scalar values. As explained on the page, callee can modify the property of the object, thereby caller can see the modified value (in case of using an object).

Another alternative, is to use a return value from the function.

EDIT:

```
Function test(p1 As String) as String
   test = "Bar"
End Function
```

c#

```
t = "foo"
t = oAccess.Run("test", t);
```